# How to allow GetBucketLocation promission on s3 bucket in order to create CA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ca, csr

In order to update the SSL certificate on AWS, CA is required for the CSR.

When I try to configure and create the CA, I get this massage:

> ValidationException The ACM Private CA Service Principal
>   'acm-pca.amazonaws.com' requires 's3:GetBucketLocation' permissions
>   for your S3 bucket 'MyBucket'. Check your S3 bucket permissions and
>   try again

To move forward with this, permission settings on Amazon S3 > *MyBucket* > Permissions > Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

According to the documentation, found here: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETlocation.html

`LocationConstraint` is required.

How to solve the "s3:GetBucketLocation" issue and create the CA?

Answer (score 5):

I once had the same issue and had to read through AWS docs.

**Configure a CRL:** Configure a certificate revocation list (CRL) if you want ACM PCA to maintain one for the certificates revoked by your private CA.

If you want to create a CRL, do the following:

1. Choose Enable CRL distribution
2. To create a new S3 bucket for your CRL entries, choose Yes for the Create a new S3 bucket option and enter a unique bucket name. Otherwise, choose No and select an existing bucket from the list.

If you choose **Yes**, ACM PCA creates the necessary bucket policy for you. If you choose **No**, make sure the following policy is attached to your bucket.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "acm-pca.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm-pca/latest/userguide/PcaCreateCa.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust your policy, make it look something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": ["s3:GetBucketLocation"],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

> Policy grants the `s3:CreateBucket`, `s3:ListAllMyBuckets`, and the `s3:GetBucketLocation` permissions to a user. Note that for all these permissions, you set the relative-id part of the Resource ARN to "*". For all other bucket actions, you must specify a bucket name.

You can also specify the ACM principle in order not to make the clause too wide.

Comment: Results in _Policy has invalid resource_ and with `MyBucket` as above it says _Policy has invalid resource_

Comment: Can you please try again, I had forgotten to add square brackets. I have double checked, it should work - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html